# Understanding the interaction between mark_line point overlay and legend

Tags: python, altair, vega-lite

I have found some unintuitive behavior in the interaction between the `point` property of `mark_line` and the appearance of the color legend for Altair/Vega-Lite.  I ran into this when attempting to create a line with very large and mostly-transparent points in order to increase the area that would trigger the line's `tooltip`, but was unable to preserve a visible `type=gradient` legend.

The following code is an MRE for this problem, showing 6 cases: the use of [`False`, `True`, and a custom `OverlayMarkDef`] for the point property and the use of plain and customized `color` encoding.

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

# create data
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['x_data'] = [0, 1, 2] * 3
df['y2'] = [0] * 3 + [1] * 3 + [2] * 3

# initialize
base = alt.Chart(df)
markdef = alt.OverlayMarkDef(size=1000, opacity=.001)
color_encode = alt.Color(shorthand='y2', legend=alt.Legend(title='custom legend', type='gradient'))
marks = [False, True, markdef]
encodes = ['y2', color_encode]

plots = []
for i, m in enumerate(marks):
    for j, c in enumerate(encodes):
        plot = base.mark_line(point=m).\
            encode(x='x_data', y='y2', color=c, tooltip=['x_data','y2']).\
            properties(title=', '.join([['False', 'True', 'markdef'][i], ['plain encoding', 'custom encoding'][j]]))
        plots.append(plot)
combined = alt.vconcat(
    alt.hconcat(*plots[:2]).resolve_scale(color='independent'),
    alt.hconcat(*plots[2:4]).resolve_scale(color='independent'),
    alt.hconcat(*plots[4:]).resolve_scale(color='independent')
).resolve_scale(color='independent')
```

The resulting plot (the interactive tooltips work as expected): [image]

The color data is the same for each of these plots, and yet the color legend is all over the place.  In my real case, the `gradient` is preferred (the data is quantitative and continuous).

- With no `point` on the `mark_line`, the legend is correct.
- Adding `point=True` converts the legend to a `symbol` type - I'm not sure why this is the case since the default legend type is `gradient` for quantitative data (as seen in the first row) and this is the same data - but can be forced back to `gradient` by the custom encoding.
- Attempting to make a custom point via `OverlayMarkDef` however renders the forced `gradient` colorbar invisible  - matching the `opacity` of the `OverlayMarkDef`.  But it is not simply a matter of the legend always inheriting the properties of the `point`, because the `symbol` legend does not attempt to reflect the `opacity`.

I would like to have the normal gradient colorbar available for the custom `OverlayMarkDef`, but I would also love to build up some intuition for what is going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transparency issue with the bottom right plot has been fixed since Altair 4.2.0, so now all occasions that include a `point` on the line changes the legend to 'Ordinal' instead of 'Quantitative'.

[image]

I believe the reason the legend is converted to a symbol instead of a gradient, is that your are adding filled points and the `fill` channel is not set to a quantitative field so it defaults to either `ordinal` or `nominal` with a sort:

```
plot = base.mark_line().encode(
    x='x_data',
    y='y2',
    color='y2',
)
plot + plot.mark_circle(opacity=1)
```

[image]

`mark_point` gives a gradient legend since it has not fill, and if we set the fill for `mark_circle` explicitly we also get a gradient legend (one for `fill` and one for `color`.

```
plot = base.mark_line().encode(
    x='x_data',
    y='y2',
    color='y2',
    fill='y2'
)
plot + plot.mark_circle(opacity=1)
```

[image]

I agree with you that this is a bit unexpected and it would be more convenient if the encoding type of `point=True` was set to the same as that used for the lines. You might suggest this as an enhancement in VegaLite together with reporting the apparent bug that you can't override the legend type via `type='gradient'`.

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful - I'm still a little confused about why we are getting different results since I am already using Altair 4.2, but it makes sense that the fill channel is somehow interfering.  I am considering using a separate invisible mark_point instead of defining the point on the line, as that appears to be less wonky with the legend - will that have a negative impact on performance?  It is listed as "equivalent" in the documentation, but that might mean "equivalent visually" only.

Comment: @fitzme You could try restarting JupyterLab, making sure there are no altair figures currently loaded in any open notebook, and then create a new notebook. Sometimes displayed figures can cause the old version of Vega-Lite to be used even if you have a newer version of Altair installed (https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/pull/2517#issuecomment-967234059).

Comment: @fitzme Regarding your second point, I don't think there is a difference. You can inspect it by creating both charts, click the three button actions menu, "Open in the Vega Editor", and then expand the Vega (not VegaLite) spec at the bottom of the page and see if it is diffferent in either case.